# Basement in a mud-brick house near a lake?

Tags: basement, humidity, ground

For the purpose of the short story that I am writing I have come with an idea of a mud-brick small building (base floor + top floor, just a few rooms), lost somewhere in the north Nigeria. The building is in a very close proximity (about 30-50 metres in a straight line) of a lake. For the sake of the story told building *must* be equipped with a basement or any other underground / below ground room.

Is this possible at all? Am I able to build anything brick-like in a damp, watery ground like you would expect in a such proximity to a lake? Would foundations and general construction guides allow such construction? If not then what is the closest distance to a lake where such building could be safely built and exist?

Temperatures in north Nigeria varies from 23 degrees Celsius during wet season to up to 40 degrees Celsius just a few last weeks of the dry season, just as a wet season is about to come. Overall air humidity during wet season can be as high as 80 percent. If that matters.

The humidity of such cellar is not a problem for me / for my story, as long as such underground room can safely exist and would allow to carry some weapons and firearms in such conditions.

I have found and read through following questions, but I don't get direct answer to my question there:

1. [Uses of a damp basement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/85549/6638)
2. [90% Humididty @ 23 Celsius direct from Air Conditioning Outlet](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/49630/6638)

I am a complete newbie to a house construction-like questions, so sorry, if this one is naive or off-topic here. Thank you.

Comment: Before digging a basement check the water level.

Comment: The old joke is that a builder digs a hole, calls it a basement and claims that it'll stay dry. A farmer digs a hole and calls it a pond. In seriousness, though, just place the dwelling on a knoll above the lake. Don't call the understory a basement -- make it a, 'pit in the floor, obviously added after the fact and haphazardly covered...'

Comment: If the ground is pretty flat between the house and the lake, the basement _will_ get wet. If the land slopes (steeply, even), it will likely be reasonably dry. You're writing the story, unless you're calling out a specific, actual lake that your readers can look up on a map, make it in a hilly area and call it good!

Comment: If the basement floor is below the level of the lake, then it's not a basement, it's a keel...